# how do I migrate a Java interface to a microservice?

Tags: java, rest, microservices

I am looking at microservices, and the possibility of migrating some of our code to this architecture.  I understand the general concept but am struggling to see how it would work for our example.

Supposing I have an interface called `RatingEngine` and an implementation called `RatingEngineImpl`, both running inside my monolithic application.  The principle is simple - The `RatingEngineImpl` could run in a different machine, and be accessed by the monolithic application via (say) a REST API, serializing the DTOs with json over http.  We even have an interface to help with this decoupling.

But how do I actually go about this?  As far as I can see, I need to create a new implementation of the interface for the rump monolith (ie now the client), which takes calls to the interface methods, converts them into a REST call, and sends them over the network to the new 'rating engine service'.  Then I also need to implement a new http server, with an endpoint for each interface method, which then deserializes the DTOs (method parameters) and routes the call to our original `RatingEngineImpl`, which sits inside the server.  Then it serializes the response and sends it back to the client.

So that seems like an awful lot of plumbing code.  It also adds maintenance overhead, since if you tweak a method in the interface you need to make changes in two more places.

Am I missing something?  Is there some clever way we can automate this boilerplate code construction?

Answer (score 2):

The Microservice pattern does not suggest you move every single service you have to it's own deployable. Only move self sustaining pieces of logic that will benefit from it's own release cycle. I.e. if your RatingEngine needs rating-logic updates weekly, but the rest of your system is pretty stable - it will likely benefit from beeing a service of it's own.

And yes - Microservices adds complexity, but not really boiler plate code of HTTP servers. There are a lot of frameworks around to deal with that. [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/) is one good. Others are Spring Boot, Apache Camel etc. A complete microservice setup could look like this with Vert.x.

```
 public class RatingService extends AbstractVerticle implements RatingEngine{
  public void start() {
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> {
      req.response()
        .putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
        .end(computeCurrentRating().encodePrettily());
    }).listen(8080);
   }

   @Override
   public int getRating(){
        return 4; // or whatever.
   }

   protected JsonObject computeCurrentRating(){
     return new JsonObject().put("rating", getRating());
   }
 }
```

Even the Java built-in framework JAX-RS helps making a microservice in not too many lines of code.

The really hard work with microservices is to add error-handling logic in the clients. Some common pitfalls

- **Microservice may go down** If call to RatingService gives connection refused exception - can you deal with it? Can you estimate a "rating" in client to not prevent further processing? Can you reuse old responses to estimate the rating? .. Or at least - you need to signal the error to support staff.
- **Reactive app?** How long can you wait for a response? A call to in memory methods will return within nano seconds, a call to an external HTTP service may take seconds or minutes depending on a number of factors. As long as the application is "reactive" and can continue to work without a "Rating" - and present the rating for the user once it's available - it's fine. If you are waiting for a blocking call to rating service, more than a few millisec. - response time becomes an obstacle. It's not as convenient/common to make reactive apps in Java as in node.js. A reactive approach will likely trigger a remake of you entire system.
- **Tolerant client** Unit/integration testing a single project is easy. Testing a complex net of microservices is not. The best thing you can do about it is to make your client call less picky. Schema validations etc. are actually bad things. In XML use single XPaths to get data you want from the response, not more not less. That way, a change in the microservice response will not require updates of all clients. JSON is a bit easier to deal with than XML in this aspect.

Comment: Tak Petter for the detailed response.  Where does my existing java interface fit in?  Does the example class also implement `RatingEngine`?  Or does the compute method simply delegate to the `RatingEngineImpl`?

Comment: Hmm.. well, I would not really try to fit in the Interface. The client might not even have a notation of Java interface as Microservice architecture suggest you can mix and match whatever languages/plattforms. The "interface" would be some json or XML message. But of course, you can implement that interface directly in the service. I have updated the example. In many frameworks there are easy ways make the call "transparent" in java. I.e. the client calls a method in a plain interface and proxies it to some HTTP rest call. It's a bit OT, but check out vert.x etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you do not miss anything substantial. The microservice architecture comes with its own cost. The one that caught your eye (boilerplate code) is one well-known item from the list. [This](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-trade-offs.html) is a very good article from Martin Fowler explaining the various advantages and disadvantages of the idea. It includes topics like:

- added complexity
- increased operational maintance cost
- struggle to keep consistency (while allowing special cases to be treated in exceptional ways)

... and many more.

Comment: I had heard that you could use clever features of spring and/or RESTeasy to magically handle some of it for you...

Comment: There are many tools designed for making your life *easier* (for deployment, monitoring, communication, etc), but they won't do the hard part for you. To be effective in adopting this technic the main prerequisite is having a certain level of maturity in your tools. From platform virtualization to experience with REST services. If you are looking for specific tools you need to do a deep investigation on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are some frameworks out there to reduce such a boilerplate code. I use Spring Boot in a current project (though not for microservices). If you already have Spring based projects, then it really simplifies the development of microservices (or any other not-Microservice-application based on Spring). Checkout some of the examples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples

Comment: Our code currently has no spring in it.  But if I've understood correctly, you can annotate either the interface, the implementation, or both, and spring boot will magically listen to http, deserialize the DTOs, and route the call to the correct method in the implementation.  Can you point me to a worked example?

Comment: *"[,..] and spring boot will magically listen to http, deserialize the DTOs, and route the call to the [...]"* - We should put this on the Christmas wishlist for Java devs: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t84854.html